# Calendar returns wrong milliseconds after Calendar.add()

Tags: java, android

```
final Date now = new Date();
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(now); 
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3); 
SetTime(c.getTimeInMillis());
```

getTimeInMillis returns the same time I have it. not +3 hours

How do I add hours to current time correctly?

Comment: If you do Calendar.getInstance() it will be the current time, you don't need the Date as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding 3 hours to another calendar instance.

Try :

```
final Date now = new Date();
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(now); 
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3); 
SetTime(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

As Peter Lawrey and Brian Roach stated, there's no need to create a Date object. So you could just do :

```
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3); 
SetTime(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: The `Date` object is completely unnecessary; `getInstance()` returns a `Calendar ` set to the current time/date.